# Creating a regex to match the following scenario

Tags: python, regex, grep

I am a student working on a small research project where I need to scrape web pages which match the following requirement :-
If word X say "abc" is found anywhere in the text, look for pattern Y say "pqr" if it occurs within a 25 character window on either side of the occurrence of X.
Eg.

`pqrxyz` is valid.

`xyz` is invalid.

`xyzpqr` is valid.

`pqr123456789123456789123456789xyz` is invalid.

I can't figure this out. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
((?=pqr).{20,}abc) | (pqr{20,}(?!abc))
```

This is my attempt so far. I don't know how to incorporate the 20 character window constraint.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to write such a regular expression yourself yet? Please post the code you've tried

Comment: You may use `r'pqr.{0,25}xyz|xyz.{0,25}pqr'`

Answer (score 0):

`.` is the regular expression for "any single character."

`{n,m}` is the regular expression for "at least n, and no more than m, repetitions of the previous regular expression."

So, the regular expression  `xyz.{0,25}pqr` means "`xyz`, followed by up to twenty-five characters, followed by `pqr`".

So, accounting for the possibility of `pqr` occurring before or after `xyz`, we get this line of python code:

```
if re.search('pqr.{0,25}xyz', line) or re.search('xyz.{0,25}pqr', line):
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, handling both cases:
`pqr.{,25}?xyz|xyz.{,25}?pqr`

I used [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/R-Y-JxmuUB2uU_eu) to test, and I think it's an easy way to show what how the regex is working.

John's answer gives more details on what the specific elements in the regex.

[Regular expression visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujL8o.png)